# How to smooth Wiener deconvolution result in Python?

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft, noise, deconvolution

I'm wondering if it is possible to smooth the estimated response from a Wiener deconvolution in order to have a better representation of the original signal and to remove the side lobes.

[image: (Here an example for an step signal)]

The recovered signal has been estimated through the Wiener deconvolution of the output signal and a kernel. I already tried to change the SNR ratio.

Comment: Your kernel is cut off at the left side. This introduces edge effects, visible as ripples in the convolution result. You might need some padding and/or windowing of your inputs.